# Hold noLoop() for certain amount of time

Tags: p5.js

I'm attempting to create a very simple "whack-a-mole" type game, designed for students new to p5.js, and Processing in general.
Currently, I've created an array, and a random search within that array that randomly picks a square and makes it brown (a "mole", for now).
How do I make it so that after selecting a square, it stays there for a couple seconds, and then jumps to the next one, using basic p5?
I've managed to implement noLoop(), which can stop the search, but after a certain time I want it to resume.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
function setup() {
    createCanvas(610,610)
}

function draw() {
    var grid = []
    for (var x = 0; x < 6; x += 1){
        grid[x]=0;
        for (var y = 0; y < 6; y += 1){
            rand=round(random(360))
            grid[x][y]=0
            if (rand==0){
                grid[x]=1
                grid[y]=1
                noLoop()
            }
            if (grid[x]==0 || grid[y]==0){
                fill(76,153,0)
                rect((x*100+10),(y*100+10),90,90)
            }
            if (grid[x]>0 && grid[y]>0){
                fill(102,51,0)
                rect((x*100+10),(y*100+10),90,90)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `noLoop()`, you could keep looping at 60 frames per second, but then use the `millis()` function to keep track of the elapsed time.

Here's an example that shows a circle for 1 second whenever the user clicks:

```
var clickTime;

function mousePressed(){
  clickTime = millis();
}

function draw() {
  background(0);
  if(millis() < clickTime + 1000){
    ellipse(width/2, height/2, width/4, height/4);
  }
}
```

**Edit:** Another approach is to use the `%` operator along with the `frameCount` variable in order to do something every X frames. This examples draws a circle in a random position every 60 frames:

```
function draw() {
  if (frameCount % 60 == 0) {
    background(0);
    ellipse(random(width), random(height), width / 4, height / 4);
  }
}
```

Comment: How would I incorporate this into my code, where if `rand==0`, then the code stops for 1-2 seconds?

Comment: @NavidMamoon Think about it this way: you don't want the code to stop. You just want to only change the mole every 60 seconds. You could also use the `frameCount` variable to do something every X frames. Please see my edited answer.

Comment: Perfect, the frameCount is exactly what I was looking for, thank you!